# Cypress executes assertion immediately on function that returns a handle

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

Cypress executing the expect assertions immediately. Not even waiting for the view to be opened at all (which takes 500ms+) .. also a `cy.wait(1000)` or `cy.get('.modalbutton').should('be.visible');` (which would make the `handle.exists()` be truthy) is completely ignored too, nothing I can do to prevent it from immediately asserting.

```
it('Open and close split view', () => {
  cy.window().then(win => {
    const handle = win.Luigi.navigation().openAsSplitView('/ext', {title: 'Preserved Split View' });
    // using cy.wait(N) or cy.get('#opened-splitview').should('be.visible'); are being ignored
    cy.wait(1000);
    // expectations are not working since they are executed immediately
    cy.expect(handle.exists()).to.be.true;
    handle.close();
    cy.expect(handle.exists()).to.be.false;
  });
});
```

On the other hand this one works:

```
cy.window().then(win => {
  const handle = win.Luigi.navigation().openAsSplitView('/ext', { title: 'Preserved Split View', collapsed: false});
  handle.collapse();
  cy.expect(handle.isCollapsed()).to.be.true;
});
```

Previously it was green when win....openAsSplitView was not saved to the handle constant and close and extra command on the Luigi.navigation() api, which I refactored to align with our client side API.

So I have the feeling it could be a bug with Cypress win interception. Or I am just using it wrong.

The handle is non-async, so immediately usable. Maybe also a refactoring to return a promise which resolves once the view is really opened would help, too.

EDIT:
It is a sort of race condition which is not handled by cypress. I have worked around it with `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  handle.close();
  setTimeout(() => {
    cy.expect(handle.exists()).to.be.false;
    cy.get('#splitViewContainer').should('not.be.visible');
    done();
  }, 50);
}, 50);
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the commented out line working? `cy.get('#opened-splitview').should('be.visible');`

Comment: Are there any requests that happen when `openAsSplitView` is called? You can wait for those to finish in order to help coordinate things. Could also try passing a timeout into the `cy.get` options

Comment: No, the `expect` is executed immediately without waiting for anything (not even `cy.wait(1e3)`. And yes, there is one request happening, the load of the view in an iframe.